# How to use a custom Axios hook outside of a React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have created a custom Axios hook called `useAxios` in my React application, which I use within function components to manage HTTP requests and state. However, I need to make Axios requests outside of function components, such as within my Redux actions. How can I use my custom Axios hook in situations where I don't have access to the component's lifecycle?

Here's a version of my `useAxios` hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import config from "../config";
import axios from "axios";

const useAxios = (axiosParams) => {
  const { method, url, requestConfig = {} } = axiosParams;

  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios[method.toLowerCase()](
          `${config.backendUrl}${url}`,
          {
            ...requestConfig,
            signal: controller.signal,
          }
        );
        console.log("res", res);
        setResponse(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading("fullfilled");
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    // clean up function
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

  return [response, error, loading];
};

export default useAxios;
```

Typically, I use it within a function component like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useAxios from "./useAxios";

function MyComponent() {
 
  const [response, error, loading] = useAxios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/data",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Data:", response);
      }
    }
  }, [response, error, loading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Dispatch Redux action that uses useAxios
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    // Render UI components
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But now, I want to use `useAxios` in Redux `createAsyncThunk` like `fetchData`, but since `useAxios` is a React hook we can't use it outside function component.

Comment: Since you know that React hooks can only be used in React function components shouldn't the solution be fairly obvious? Just call the `axios` functions directly like you would anywhere else in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal javascript function and call that function anywhere you want.

```js
import config from "../config";
import axios from "axios";

const ApiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.backendUrl,
  // others config you want to add.
});
```

then you can call this function like this from anywhere.

```js
ApiClient.get("/api/data");
```